# VS2005 .NET 2.0 and C# and x86 target platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, x86, uac

I use VS2005 on Windows Vista.
I create a very simple Windows application in C# using .NET 2.0, a form with a close button.

Due to a necessary library, I need the VS-option target platform "x86". If I build on Vista and transfer the application to a X64 Windows 7 computer, the application requires administrator rights for execution (UAC-Message-Dialog), which I want to avoid.

If using the VS-option target platform "anyCPU", this works fine, but I need a solution for the target platform "x86".

Can anybody help me?

What I want to do is to change the code or the project configuration to avoid the UAC-Message-Dlg on Windows7 (x64). But I don’t know what I have to do. I need the option “x86”, because we want to use an x86 library. The test code is totally simple (see below), so I presume the problem is in the project configuration:

```
// Project code:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Updater2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1( )
    {
      InitializeComponent( );
    }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
      Close( );
    } // -- toolStripButtonClose_Click
  } // - Form1
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be whatever the program requires administrator rights, so without the code, we can't really advise you on how to resolve your problem.  Targeting against `anyCPU` would allow you to run the program on either `x86` or `x64` operating systems but on `Windows 7` it would still bring up the UAC depending on what the program actually does.  What exactly is your question?  I can tell you "Can anyone help me" isn't a on topic question.

Comment: This is simple to solve in VS2008 and up, Project + Add New Item, Application Manifest File.  High time to update.

Comment: What I want to do is to change the code or the project configuration to avoid the UAC-Message-Dlg on Windows7 (x64). But I don’t know what I have to do. I need the option “x86”, because we want to use an x86 library. The test code is totally simple (see below), so I presume the problem is in the project configuration:
I can not insert the code, because the number of characters is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you are trying to write files to the C:/ or C:/Program Files folder. Try writing any files to the `%Current User%` folder to avoid UAC. Apart from that, without seeing any of your code, I can't offer much more of a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the word "**Update**" in the program name.

When an executable has words like "Update", "Install" or "Setup" in its name, Windows assumes it may be an installer which will most likely require administrative rights. So, these programs are forced to run with an elevation prompt on UAC-enabled systems.

It's not just the executable name either. If renaming the file does not solve the problem, the application might have these keywords in its version information too. Having the following will result in the same behavior:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Setup DVD Player")] 
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("Instal President")] // Yes, even with the misspelling.
```

Easy way out is to rename the application and to avoid using these keywords.

Proper way out is including an application manifest in the executable.